# Objective C Empty Child Class Implementation

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, derived-class

I have a base class Person and would like to create a derived class that would not have any custom implementation - all properties and methods are declared and implemented in the base class. I get errors saying:

- Cannot find interface declaration for 'Person', superclass of 'Employee';
- Class 'Employee' defined without specifying a base class.

I am probably missing something; please help. How do I fix those errors?

**Person.h**

```
@interface Person : NSObject 

@end
```

**Person.m**

```
#import "Person.h"

@interface Person ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation Person {}

- (void)print {
   NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
}

@end
```

**Employee.h**

```
@interface Employee : Person

@end
```

**Employee.m**

```
#import "Employee.h"

@implementation Employee {}

@end
```

Comment: Is `Person.h` imported in `Employee.h`?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the import statement. Everything is working now. Thank you so much!